# is $|x|^3$ differentiable at [-1, 2]

Tags: real-analysis

I first defined the function for $x$>0 and $x$<0.

For $x$>0 the function is $x^3$

For $x$<0 function is =-$x^3$

I differentiated it and both cases turned out to be 0.

so left hand limit=RHL=0.

So the function must be differentiable.

am I correct?

Comment: $f(x)=-x^3$ is a polynomial, and so is differentiable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{|h|^3-|0|^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^+} h^2 =0$$
And
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{|h|^3-|0|^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{-h^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^+} -h^2 =0$$
So $|x|^3$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and its derivative is $0$.

In any other $x \in [-1,2] \setminus \{0\}$ you can use the usual derivative rules since there aren't problems with the derivative.

Comment: thank you for your time :)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
If there's function $g(x)=|f(x)|\\$
$g'(x) = sgn(f(x)).f'(x)$

Comment: This isn’t always true. Take $f(x) = 0$, $g = |f| = 0$.

Comment: I've edited it. Got carried away.

Comment: It’s still false if $f(a) = f’(a) = 0$ at some $a$, see Dunkelheit’s answer above.

Comment: In fact the function $|x^3|$ is differentiable at $0.$ Look at the graph, for example. But a better reason is that unlike for $|x|,$ the derivative from both sides is $0,$ which by definition we all agree to be $\pm 0.$ This never happens when the derivative for $x>0$ is nonzero. Then you always have a cusp.

Comment: Yeah that's true, whenever f'(a)=f(a)=0 for some a then my statement won't hold. But what I've written now, that's correct for all functions.